# IIS redirect a subdirectory to a root-level directory with the same name

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewrite-module

I want to setup a redirect in IIS that redirects all multi-level URLs on my site that end in `/blog` to a root-level subdirectory called `/blog`. For example, `https://www.example.com/sub1/sub2/blog` would redirect to `https://www.example.com/blog`.

I wrote the following regex pattern:

```
blog/?$
```

The problem is that while this does match `https://www.example.com/sub1/sub2/blog`, it also matches `https://www.example.com/blog`, which is itself the URL I'm redirecting to. Therefore, hitting `/sub1/sub2/blog` redirects to `/blog`, which itself matches and redirects to `/blog`, etc., causing it to get stuck in a loop redirecting to itself.

How do I write the regex pattern so that a multi-level URL that ends in `/blog` will redirect to the root-level `/blog` page, without the root-level page itself matching?

Comment: Add a condition to check if "^blog" matches, and don't redirect in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
 <rule name="rewrite rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/(.+)/blog/?$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/blog" redirectType="Temporary" />
                </rule>
```

Or you can whitlist

```
  <rule name="rewrite rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="blog/?$" />
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/blog/?$" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/blog" redirectType="Temporary" />
                </rule>
```